# SQL querying data based on the timestamp difference

Tags: mysql, sql, database, influxdb

I have a problem related to the sql databases.

Namely I want to create a query get the average value of a certain measurment column, but only for those subsequent rows whose time difference is less than 60 seconds.

An example table would look something like this:

```
| ID | Measurement | Timestamp | 
| 1  | 0.564       | 1535648400|
| 2  | 0.456       | 1535648459|
| 3  | 0.785       | 1535648501|
| 4  | 0.321       | 1535648620|
```

The difference between the timestamps would be ok for all rows, except between 3 and 4, where they differ for more than 60 seconds. In that case, average would not take row with ID 4, but only the first 3 rows.

Primarily I plan to write this query for a InfluxDB database, but generally a query also for a structural SQL would work as well.

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to follow without desired results.  Also, which database are you using?  InfluxDB is very different from MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  The actual table measrument is a bit longer and the query as well, but I did not want to make additional confusions. For me it is important to see how primarily such a query would look like in InfluxDB for any similar example, or if not there, at least in something like MySQL, since while the databases are different, the query language is not that much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join table to itself using inner join with timestamp condition to include all records for 60 seconds. Standard SQL below (need to be adjusted for InfluxDB):

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.measurement, t1.timestamp,  avg(t2.measurement) 
FROM table t1, table t2
WHERE t1.timestamp <= t2.timestamp
  AND t1.timestamp + 60*1000 > t2.timestamp
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.measurement, t1.timestamp
```

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add an extra answer on top of V.G.'s that I found very good. For performance reasons, you may want to rephrase the query and add a good index, as in:

```
create index ix1 on table (timestamp);
```

Then the query could be:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.measurement, t1.timestamp,  avg(t2.measurement) 
FROM table t1, table t2
WHERE t2.timestamp >= t1.timestamp
  AND t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp + 60*1000
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.measurement, t1.timestamp
```

Sometimes, a simple "query rephrase" can make a big performance difference.